# Serverless Lambda re-run function on error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

My lamba function works the way it is supposed to work, however sometimes it gives an error. But with a manual re-run it works fine. So I was thinking to have an automatic retry when ever that error occurs.

Now I am new to Serverless so I was hoping to ask how do I do I invoke retries on failure/error. I have tried searching but was not successful. I'd be happy if someone can guide me with this.

Thanks :)

Comment: You can use promises to catch the error and then re-invoke your lambda using the lambda API https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property

Comment: AWS team discourages from building your own retry logic inside lambda, depending on your use case you might want to use [aws step functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions), at least for more complex work flows

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you should look at your lambda maximum execution time.
By default it's 3 seconds, maybe sometimes your function is longer and then fails.

[This document](https://blog.rowanudell.com/understand-your-lambda-event-retries/) explains lambda retries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is not with the execution time. 
It gives a "Socket Hang up" error. But a re-try bypasses it. So that's why I was thinking of having an automatic retry

Comment: `{
  "errorMessage": "socket hang up",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1137:19)",
    "Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)",
    "emitNone (events.js:111:20)",
    "TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)",
    "endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)",
    "_combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)",
    "process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)"
  ]
}`

Comment: Which version of nodejs do you use as your lambda runtime ? This post says that was fixed in Node8 : https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/issues/31

Comment: I'm using 8.10. But I was able to fix the issue. I am using axios, which was giving me the error

Answer (score 0):

Before you proceed, you need to make sure you understand where the error is being generated.

If your lambda function itself makes some kind of socket connection while it runs, and the lambda function gets a "Socket Hang Up" exception during execution, it probably returns a 5xx status code your calling application. You can have your lambda function retry whatever it was doing using any kind of common retry technique.

If your calling application is seeing the Socket Hang Up exception, then the issue is actually in the communication between your application and AWS Lambda, and adding retries *inside* your lambda function will be useless. You need to add the retries to your calling application.

Here's an example of what that might look like:

```
function getUsers() {
    let retries = 0;
    let maxAttempts = 3;

    function attempt() {
        return lambda.invoke({
            ClientContext: "MyApp", 
            FunctionName: "GetUsers",
            Payload: JSON.stringify({ Active: true })
        }).promise().catch(error => {
            // We don't want to retry on EVERY error, because the error might
            // be an application error or an AWS credentials error. So here we
            // check specifically for the types of errors to retry. AWS will
            // helpfully set the "retryable" property if it's a network issue
            // that they caught.
            //
            // A socket connection might not be an AWS-generated error, so you
            // need to check it directly... this is just an example you can
            // extend:
            if (error.retryable || error.code === 'ECONNRESET') {
                retries++;
                if (retries < maxAttempts) {
                    return attempt();
                }
            }
            throw error;
        });
    }

    return attempt();
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention: I am assuming right now that it is your application calling code that needs the retry, not the lambda function.  If you prove that is not true, you can still use the template above; just replace the `attempt()` function body with whatever socket connection your lambda function is attempting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to figure out the issue. 
I am using axios, which was giving me the Socket Hang up error. I was able to handle it in the catch block.